# Problems accessing a dictionary/json in a javascript function to populate a table

Tags: javascript, python, iframe

Overview:
I am creating a web page using Python and generating both html as well as javascript in my code. Additionally, I am parsing through csv files and converting their table data to html. I want to be able to click on a line of text and the associated table data for that text would then be loaded into an iframe on the currently active web page. The problem I am having, is that my javascript function is not recognizing the key I send it to retrieve the corresponding table data. If I manually enter the key to return the table data, the correct data is returned - though the table doesn't load. However, if I generate the key programmatically, it returns as 'undefined' even though the strings appear to be identical.

Goal:
I need to figure out if there is something wrong with either the syntax, or the format of the key I am using to try and retrieve the table data. Secondly, I need to figure out why the table data is not being correctly loaded into my iframe.

Example:

```
import pandas

opening_html =  """<!DOCTYPE html><h1> Test</h1><div style="float:left">"""
table_html = pandas.DataFrame({'Col_1':['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']}).to_html()
tables_dict = {'test-1 00': table_html}
java_variables = "%s" % json.dumps(tables_dict)
table_frame = """<iframe name="table_frame" style="position:fixed; top:100px; width:750; height:450"></iframe>"""
test_link_text = """<a href='' onclick="send_table_data(this);"> test-1</a><br>"""
java = """<script type='text/javascript'>
            var table_filename = """ + java_variables + ";"
            
java += """function send_table_data(obj) {
            var t = obj.text + ' 00';
            alert(t)
            //This line below will not work
            var table_data = table_filename[t];
            //But this line will return the correct value
            var table_data = table_filename['test-1 00'];
            alert(table_data);
            //This line should load the data, but does nothing
            document.getElementsByName('table_frame').src = table_data;
        }
        </script>"""

html_text = """<head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                </head>""" + test_link_text + table_frame + """<body>""" + "</div>" + java + '</body>'

with open('test_table_load.html', 'w') as w:
    w.write(html_text)
```

EDIT: I did just figure out that for some reason there was a default space at the beginning of the var t - so using trim() seemed to fix that. Now, the only issue left is why the data doesn't load into the table.

Comment: To get rid of the "default space", just remove the space from "> test-1</a><be>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you figured out your typo with the space that was messing with your key, so this is for your second question.

## Your code

So to get your table to populate in the iframe you need to fix three things:

1. To edit the HTML contents of your iframe you should be setting the `.srcdoc` element, not `.src`
2. The `document.getElementsByName()` function will return an array of HTML elements so in order to get the element you want you should do one of the following:

   - (recommended) switch to using `document.getElementById` and use `id='table_frame'` in your iframe tags
   - select the first element of the array by using `document.getElementsByName('table_frame')[0]`
3. The anchor tag that you're using as the trigger for your function is redirecting you back to the original HTML page, stopping you from seeing any of the changes your javascript function is making. A simple solution to this is to switch to using a `<button>` element in place of `<a>`.

Here is what your code looks like with the fixes:

```py
import pandas
import json

opening_html =  """<!DOCTYPE html><h1>Test</h1><div style="float:left">"""
table_html = pandas.DataFrame({'Col_1':['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']}).to_html()
tables_dict = {'test-1 00': table_html}
java_variables = "%s" % json.dumps(tables_dict)
table_frame = """<iframe id="table_frame" style="position:fixed; top:100px; width:750; height:450"></iframe>"""
test_link_text = """<button href='' onclick="send_table_data(this);"> test-1</button><br>"""
java = """<script type='text/javascript'>
            var table_filename = """ + java_variables + ";"
            
#for the button, innerText needs to be used to get the button text
java += """function send_table_data(obj) {
            var t = obj.innerText + ' 00';
            alert(t)
            //This line below will not work
            var table_data = table_filename[t];
            //But this line will return the correct value
            var table_data = table_filename['test-1 00'];
            alert(table_data);
            //This line should load the data, but does nothing
            document.getElementById('table_frame').srcdoc = table_data;
        }
        </script>"""

html_text = """<head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                </head>""" + test_link_text + table_frame + """<body>""" + "</div>" + java + '</body>'

with open('test_table_load.html', 'w') as w:
    w.write(html_text)
```

## Other Recommendations

I *strongly* suggest looking into some python frameworks that can assist you in generating your website, either using HTML templates like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/), or a library that can assist in generating HTML using Python. (I would recommend [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/introduction) for your current use case)

Comment: Thanks for your input and suggestions. I was getting a feeling there was a problem with viewing the 'updated' page after changing the table data, I just didn't know how to resolve it. I think your answer will eventually work for me, but right now I can no longer get the data from my dictionary. The obj.text line now returns an undefined error. If I can get that fixed, I think this will work.

Comment: Got it working. I just changed obj.text to obj.innerText and it returned the desired result.